# Specializing a variadic template template parameter on the minimum number of arguments: legal or not?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, variadic-templates

I have code:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<template<typename...> class>
struct Foo 
{ 
    enum { n = 77 };
};

template<template<typename, typename...> class C>
struct Foo<C>
{
    enum { n = 99 }; 
};

template<typename...> struct A { };

template<typename, typename...> struct B { };

int main(int, char**)
{
    printf("%d\n", Foo<A>::n);
    printf("%d\n", Foo<B>::n);
}
```

The idea is that `template<typename, typename...> class` is a subset of `template<typename...> class`, so it might be possible to specialize on it. But it's pretty esoteric, so maybe not. Let's try it out.

GCC 4.7 says:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test157.cpp
```

It compiled!

Running it:

```
$ ./a.out 
77
99
```

It works!

Clang 3.1 says:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 test157.cpp
test157.cpp:10:8: error: class template partial specialization does not specialize any template argument; to define the primary template, remove the template argument list
struct Foo<C>
       ^  ~~~
test157.cpp:9:10: error: too many template parameters in template template parameter redeclaration
template<template<typename, typename...> class C>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test157.cpp:3:10: note: previous template template parameter is here
template<template<typename...> class>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

Who's right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clang is wrong to reject the partial specialization. To know how to interpret the errormessage, you need to understand what clang diagnoses. It means to diagnose a partial specialization whose arguments match exactly the implicit argument list of the primary class template (`<param1, param2, ... , paramN>`).

However the argument lists are differently so clang shall not diagnose it. In particular this has nothing to do wheter the partial specialization matches more or less arguments. Consider

```
template<typename A, typename B> class C;
template<typename B, typename A> class C<A, B> {};
```

The partial specialization here matches everything and not more that the primary template would match. And the argument lists of both templates are different so this partial specialization is valid, just like you'rs.

Comment: Thank you. Fascinating example. Thinking about it, my example was just a specific case of the general one of specializing a variadic template template parameter to any more-specific number of parameters (say, two). If I try to make a specialization of `Foo` for `template<typename, typename> class` I get the same behaviour: GCC accepts, Clang rejects. I'll file a bug (if it hasn't been done). A cite from the standard would make me happy, if it's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 4):

```
`template<template<typename, typename...> class C>
```

is no more specialized than

```
template<template<typename...> class>
```

Both of them takes a list of unknown type parameters. it is just that the former takes one member of this list as a different parameter. 
It contains no additional info about the type such that the compiler should select one over the other.

In the typical usage of variadic templates this specialization is generated in terms of parameter count. Thinking about the variadic templates as recursive functions during runtime, you should just supply the terminating condition (as a class taking only one unknown type).

Clang is very keen on diagnostics so I think it is catching the abnormality and rightfully  giving errors. 
GCC's being able to compile it is strange. Maybe because you are explicitly specifying which templates to use in `struct A` and `struct B` seperately, gcc was able to catch that and suppress the abnormality.

Comment: There's a difference. One of them matches "class templates with zero or more typename parameters", the other matches "class templates with one or more typename parameters". Indeed, if you try to pass `template<typename...> struct A { }` as a template argument where the parameter is of type `template<typename, typename...> class`, both Clang and GCC will reject it. Of course this doesn't mean that the language standard also allows for specialization based on this distinction. If you provide a cite I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Put another way, if it's possible to specialize based on the number of arguments when they're in a positive position -- `template<typename...>` versus `template<typename, typename...>` -- I see no theoretical obstacle to also allowing it when they're in a negative position, `template<template<typename...> class>` versus `template<template<typename, typename...> class>`. What I'm uncertain about is whether the ISO standard makes provisions for it.